# How to transpose the lat/lon coordinates of a shapefile?

Tags: qgis, arcmap, coordinate-system

I need X to be Y and Y to be X (switching lat/long) within the polygon shapefile. If it were a point shapefile I know I could simply reverse the lat/long or x/y parameter and import from a table. I'm not sure how to do something similar with a polygon layer. Is there any editing tool that would accomplish this? I have QGIS and ArcMap 9.3 ArcInfo licensing available. Its projected as WGS 1984.

I'm working with a large polygon file so manually changing it would be very tedious. Any thoughts on how to do this?

Comment: Do you have some sample data you could like to so people could have a better idea of what you are starting with and what you need?

Comment: Makes me wonder why [Warp](http://resourcesbeta.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00170000007v000000) is constrained to only work with rasters.  Otherwise it might be handy in this situation.

Comment: It is data that needs to be overlaid on a layer of US states polygons and is roughly a bunch of polygons around major cities (so tampa is in the northwest and vancouver washington is southeast if you can visualize that). Megadrofan's answer below is exactly what I needed to get this to work.  I believe it essential flips the lat/long of every single vertex of every polygon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no out of box solution in ArcGIS. But you can use scripts to achieve this. Try this form arcscripts catalog
http://resources.arcgis.com/gallery/file/Geoprocessing-Model-and-Script-Tool-Gallery/details?entryID=DDFDC6B9-1422-2418-7FA8-E61F0683523D

Comment: Link found to be dead.

Answer (score 0):

For QGIS, to achieve this effect, just use the *SWAP XY* plugin available in the extensions in current QGIS (2.12 at the answer time)

Comment: Plugin does not seem to be available in QGIS 3.4.6, you can find the plugin here: https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/swapXY/ Probably will need a python 2 environment to get this running.